# Photoshop Javascript scripting saving and closing document

Tags: javascript, scripting, photoshop

I'm having trouble saving for some reason; 
I'm using Photoshop CS5.1 (if that really is the cause of the issue)

```
error 8800: General Photoshop error occurred. 
This functionality may not be available in this version of Photoshop.
Could not save a copy as C:\...\Temp001.jpeg0011338281522" 
because the file could not be found
```

```
var thistimestamp = Math.round(new Date().getTime() / 1000);
saveFile = new File( "/Users/Barny/My Pictures/Temp001" +thistimestamp+ ".jpeg" )
saveOptions = new JPEGSaveOptions();
saveOptions.embedColorProfile = true;
saveOptions.formatOptions = FormatOptions.STANDARDBASELINE;
saveOptions.matte = MatteType.NONE;
saveOptions.quality = 9;
app.activeDocument.saveAs(saveFile, saveOptions, true,Extension.LOWERCASE);
```

I'd like the script to save and close, but I keep getting this error. I'm using Photoshop CS5.1 (if that really is the cause of the issue)

Comment: In what context is your JS running?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you get the error `General Photoshop error` while saving it usually means a problem with the save path. Photoshop is trying to save to a location that doesn't exist. This works assuming the folder `C:/Users/Barney/Pictures/Temp001` exists:

```
var thistimestamp = Math.round(new Date().getTime() / 1000);
saveFile = new File( "c:/Users/Barney/Pictures/Temp001/" +thistimestamp)
saveOptions = new JPEGSaveOptions();
saveOptions.embedColorProfile = true;
saveOptions.formatOptions = FormatOptions.STANDARDBASELINE;
saveOptions.matte = MatteType.NONE;
saveOptions.quality = 9;

app.activeDocument.saveAs(saveFile, saveOptions, true,Extension.LOWERCASE);
```

The only changes I made were to to the path string `saveFile = new File("C:/Users/Barney/Pictures/Temp001/" + thistimestamp)` Notice I added the `C:` to make it an absolute path and added a `/` after Temp001 to specify this is a folder and not part of the final file name. `My Pictures` should actually be `Pictures` (my pictures is just an alias), which is what you get if you copy the address from the address bar. Also I removed the `+ ".jpeg"` because photoshop takes care of the file extension for you.

If you're trying to create a new folder you have to use the `Folder` object:

```
var myfolder = new Folder("c:/Users/Barney/Pictures/Temp001/");
myfolder.create();
```