# Photoshop javascript save error 8800

Tags: windows-7, save, photoshop-script, jsx

In my javascript, in Windows 7, Photoshop CS2 & Photoshop CS5, it throws an error:

> Error 8800: General Photoshop error occurred. This functionality may not be available in this version of Photoshop.
>   - Could not save a copy as "C:...\wcb-010B-11Y.jpg" because the file could not be found.
>   Line: 458 
>   ->    docRef.saveAs( saveFile, jpgSaveOptions, true, Extension.LOWERCASE );

here is a summary of the code to save the image:

```
var selectedSaveDir = "~/Desktop/";
var sFileNamePreFix = "wcb-";
var docRef = app.activeDocument; 
var docName = app.activeDocument.name;
var docNewName = docName.substr( 0, docName.length - 4 );  // strip file extension
var sNewDocName = sFileNamePreFix + docNewName + ".jpg"
var sNewFileName = selectedSaveDir + sNewDocName;
//alert( "sNewFileName = " + sNewFileName );     // test to verify correct location
var saveFile = new File(sNewFileName);
jpgSaveOptions = new JPEGSaveOptions();
jpgSaveOptions.quality = 12;
docRef.saveAs(saveFile, jpgSaveOptions, true, Extension.LOWERCASE);
```

In Windows XP, this script works very well in CS2 with no problems.... just in Windows 7 is where this issue occurs using CS2 or CS5.

The problem seems to be similar to : [Photoshop Javascript scripting saving and closing document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10795983/photoshop-javascript-scripting-saving-and-closing-document)
But I don't know his OS.

I've added the "alert(" and confirmed the save folder & name is correct and can be saved to, but same issue.

Could it be a UAC issue in Windows 7 ? and how do you Fix it ?  I've turned off all UAC settings (I think I did it correctly), but it still occurs.

Any Help ?

Answer (score 0):

You missed out " var docRef = app.activeDocument;" (which i've added); but apart from that, in CS2 the script saves out a jpeg to the desktop (wcb-text test.jpg). It's obvious, but have you made sure the image is flattened or doesn't contain any information that cannot be stored in a jpeg - like paths for example.

Try forcing a flatten before saving

```
//flatten the image
docRef.flatten();
```

Another thing to try is to save out the file to another directory. I know that long file names (especially with spaces in) can cause problems - I think there's a limit to 300 characters in the file path.

Answer (score 0):

I just found that, in new versions of PS this particular path variable gives the error 8800:

```
var selectedSaveDir = "~/Desktop/";
```

Use full path instead and use apostrophes instead of quotes:

```
var selectedSaveDir = 'C:/Users/yourname/Desktop/';
```